# Cannot find Apache configuration files in 15.10, did they change location?

Tags: apache2, 15.10

I installed `apache2`, but I couldn't change charset and language - when I went to try and edit the configuration files, the files were not present in `/etc/apache2`, which was an empty folder.

Where are `httpd.conf` and the other configuration files?  Have their locations changed in the Apache version on 15.10?

Comment: The location for Apache configuration files hasn't changed - it should still all be in `/etc/apache2/...`

Comment: there is no httpd.conf apache2.conf    conf-enabled  mods-available  sites-available   envvars       mods-enabled    sites-enabled
conf-available  magic         ports.conf

Answer (score 0):

The location for Apache configuration files has not changed - it's still `/etc/apache2/...`.

Given your comments in response to my initial poke in the comments, it sounds like your Apache conf files were erased, which is a bad thing.  Or you have a broken package, which explains the configuration files not existing.

---

We can usually repair the defaults by reinstalling whatever folder contains the configurations.  Though, sometimes we have to do a complete reinstall of Apache in its entirety, by purging the existing installation and reinstalling.

**First try: Package reinstall**

This will reinstall the `apache2` package, which I believe contains the default configuration setups; this should install new copies of configs.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```

If this fails, though, and there are not new copies of default configurations available in `/etc/apache2`, then we need to do a more forceful approach involving a removal and purge (to get rid of any leftover configs) and then a full reinstall of the Apache core packages...

**Second try: Remove apache2, and reinstall**

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
```

Comment: it doesn t work. I think "in 15.10 there was no httpd.conf"